# Rails MultiJson::LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, httparty

I am trying to fetch a json feed and get a MultiJson::LoadError

The reason is that in the feed there is a trailing "," after the last node.

```
{"first_element" : "value", "second_element" : "value",}
```

Is there a way to output json without the LoadError. Is there a raw function which ignores this.

I am using httParty to fetch the url

Comment: That's not valid JSON, so there's no well-written library that will allow you to output it as JSON... I'm sure there's a way to get around this, but the best answer is to get the feed to output valid JSON